# Does the commander count as part of your deck?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Say I have an EDH/Commander deck with Omnath, Locus of Mana as my commander.

Does that count as being in my deck?

Or can I have another Omnath, Locus of Mana in my deck?  (If so I imagine I would have to follow all the Legendary rules about playing the second one.)

If I could include a second one in my deck that could be useful (if the commander version gets killed a few times I would be able to play the one from the deck for only 3 mana.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, the Commander is part of the deck.

> 903.5a Each deck must contain exactly 100 cards, including its commander.

The Legend rule doesn't limit what can be present in a deck — it limits what's on the 'field — but the following Commander rule does:

> 903.5b Other than basic lands, each card in a Commander deck must have a different English name.

The uniqueness rule extends to the sideboard. You only have a single copy of a card in both the deck and 10 card sideboard combined.

Comment: You also might want to mention that if you use the optional sideboard rule, you may still only have a single copy of a card in both the 100 card deck and 10 card sideboard combined.

Comment: @user1873, It would be silly to place one there as you couldn't add it to your deck without breaking the uniqueness rule, but I mentioned it nonetheless.

Comment: @ikegami But you could Wish for it.

Answer (score -5):

No. The commander itself does not count as part of the deck. When you are playing EDH your Commander is technically off the board when it is in the command zone. So before you even start playing an EDH/Commander game the Commander is not in the deck. Ergo it does not count as part of your 100-card restriction.

Comment: This answer is wrong. The rule quoted by the earlier answer is still part of the latest CR [Jan 16, 2016]: "*903.5a Each deck must contain exactly 100 cards, **including its commander**.*" The EDH site confirms: "*A Commander deck must contain exactly 100 cards, **including the Commander**.*"